# Application error while opening URL for app deployed in Heroku

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, deployment, backend

I have deployed my webpage on Heroku, with MongoAtlas for hosting database. The site has been deployed successfully, but on opening the URL it shows the following error.

> An error occurred in the application and your page could not be
>   served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.
>   You can do this from the Heroku CLI with the command heroku logs
>   --tail

The logs show this

```
2020-06-10T10:31:25.558083+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2020-06-10T10:31:25.676299+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2020-06-10T10:31:25.723593+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-06-11T04:42:15.117508+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=immense-harbor-74512.herokuapp.com request_id=cd4e6bba-2b33-447a-9b73-da66c77c4946 fwd=
"47.9.8.24" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-06-11T04:42:15.971379+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=immense-harbor-74512.herokuapp.com request_id=b5b1c208-bd9e-48b3-9c96-d8b79a
af9123 fwd="47.9.8.24" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-06-11T04:42:37.965020+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=immense-harbor-74512.herokuapp.com request_id=52f3dcab-4f12-41cd-96dd-12856fbfb240 fwd=
"47.9.8.24" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

What is the problem and how to solve it

Comment: Have you added the `Procfile` that describes the beginning command of your application?

Comment: The reason why the app crashed is missing in the logs. Try to run `heroku logs --num=50` and show us more logs